# Entered text causing textarea to expand outside of div after form submit

Tags: css, textarea

I have a form that is driving me nuts.  The form contains several textareas as input fields.  When copying and pasting or just typing the data into the textarea everything is fine.  However, when I submit the form and it re-displays, the textarea has now expanded, outside of its container div, to accommodate any text that has no spaces in it and overflows the width.  Should it not wrap like it did when first entered?  And if so, how do I get it to stop expanding the textarea?

Examples:

Before from submit:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBbJL.png]

After form submit:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjfRz.png]

```css
#incexfrm {
    width: 675px;
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
.category textarea {
    height: 100%;
    width: 99%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The `#incexfrm` id is the CSS for the container.  The `.category` class contains the CSS for the various textareas on the form.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm assuming that you're building ASP web application or website. If so I would recommend you to use `class` instead of `id`, as `id` might be changed by the application itself... Lets know, if it helped.

Comment: No, the site is coded in Perl CGI.

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the HTML?

Answer (score -1):

As per your question, I have suggested you to use the following code-
Here your textarea must be in category class

```
#incexfrm { 
    width: 675px; 
    background-color: #d9d9d9; 
    border: 2px solid black; 
}

.category { 
    width: 100%; 
}

.category textarea { 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 99%; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```